# Playscape SDK 1.17 android apk crash on start

Tags: playscape

Unity3D v5.3.2f1

Created empty project without any scripts, simple scene with Playscape object on it.

1 - Imported Playscape SDK 1.17

2 - Imported Google Play SDK 0.9.30

3 - Configured Playscape and Google Play.

4 - Compile android build

5 - On different android devices apk crash on begin.

[Playscape config](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PxR9B.jpg)

Log from device:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/zhwvtsqbkew07ed/Terminal%20Saved%20Output?dl=0

Comment: You get such exception: 
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed resolution of: Lcom/google/android/gms/analytics/GoogleAnalytics

Looks like google play services wasn't putted into your build. May be you stripped your google-play-services.jar and stripped `analytics` module from it. Check that, please.

Comment: I tested many times and installed this plugin : https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/unity/v3/?hl=ru (if it needed) but unfortunately anyway is the same error, and BTW if I delete Playscape SDK from project everything work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, `Playscape SDK` doesn't support `Google Play SDK 0.9.30` for now. Please use `Google Play SDK 0.9.21`.

Comment: Unfortunately Unity3D 5.3.2 with Google Play SDK 0.9.21 is not compatible, in engine from vers.5.3 is changed Social Platform library.
I tried to change manually Google Play SDK to avoid "warnings", but it not worth, also as to convert all project to the older version of unity3d. 

Probably need to fix this problem with another way. 
May be to import all compatible libs manually (Playscape SDK 1.17 + Google Play 0.9.30 + libs what is missed), but carufully in case if again something is not compatible with new SocialPlatform from unity